# Encode issues in Eloquent's model object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, encoding, model

I'm trying to return value (city) from model. The city (more like town) is called "Nakło nad Notecią".

This is Laravel/Eloquent.

In model:

```
public function getCity(): string
{
    return $this->city;
}
```

The result of above function is

> Nak\u0142o nad Noteci\u0105

so obviously it's encoding issue.
The result of function

```
$model->getAttributes();
```

is an array of all fields, among whom is city, properly encoded.
Function

```
$model->getAttribute('city');
```

also returns improper encoded string.

This issue is occured in production and I cannot use xDebug to check it. It's gonna take me some time to simulate above in my local env, so maybe someone will have some sort of quick fix.

If I manage to make this work, I will publish more details and solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Came across something like this the other day. Check your MySQL encoding, as that could be the culprit.

Comment: It's utf-8 and it's saved properly - its Nakło nad Notecią in database.